# Is it possible to set the TargetFramework on the commandline with dotnet build / restore?

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

I want to remove the TargetFramework specifier from my project files and pass it via the commandline. Sounds easy:

```
dotnet build -f net5
```

But the big problem is the NuGet aspect. Because

```
dotnet restore
```

complains about the missing framework:

> dotnet restore common\common.csproj
> Determining projects to restore...
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(92,5): error NETSDK1013: The **TargetFramework value '' was not recognized.** It may be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly.

The problem is that `dotnet restore` does not accept a TargetFamework argument. So I am forced to write the TargetFramework into the config file: Even worse, there is always a single NuGet restoration in the `obj` directories, so upon every switch between target frameworks I need to modify the config file and do a fresh restore. This is extremely cumbersome and I wonder how this can be avoided.

If this cannot be solved I would kick out NuGet and reference the package assemblies directly.

Comment: Try `dotnet restore -p:TargetFramework=net5.0`

Comment: I would say that works! The-p switch appears to be undocumented (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore). How do you know?

Comment: It's documented in [msbuild docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-the-same-source-files-with-different-options?view=vs-2019#specify-properties-on-the-command-line). `dotnet restore` actually is `dotnet msbuild -t:restore`, so any switch for msbuild works with `restore` or `build`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` are wrappers around `dotnet msbuild`, you can use all MSBuild switches to change behavior of build system.

Here we need to set target framework, which can be done by

- setting property in project file: `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`

OR

- setting property through command line [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-the-same-source-files-with-different-options?view=vs-2019#specify-properties-on-the-command-line): `dotnet restore -p:TargetFramework=net5.0`

OR

- setting environment variable

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was curious about why setting an environment variable for the TargetFramework is not recommended. Could you share some insights on this? I appreciate your help!

Comment: @JorgeGonzales, environment variables are very handy in CI/CD scenarios. I was talking about case when setting environment variables is necessary, e.g. repository have something like `beforeBuild.sh` which sets bunch on environment variables in developer machine. It's not practical and interferes with other projects.