# How to dotnet restore a multi-target framework in CI for testing using old version of dotnet?

Tags: c#, testing, github-actions, nuget-package-restore, multitargeting

I have a C# package which currently supports dotnet 8 and I'm trying to modify it to add dotnet 6 and 7 support as well. I've gotten it to build for all versions using dotnet 8 locally on my laptop, using `<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net7.0;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>` in the `.csproj` file and removing all C# features added after net6.0. However when I push it to GitHub and my workflow runs in Github Actions, I test it against dotnet 6 and 7 as well as 8, and it breaks on the `dotnet restore` step.

My workflow:

```yaml
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

env:
  DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: true
  DOTNET_GENERATE_ASPNET_CERTIFICATE: false

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest
    name: .NET ${{ matrix.dotnet }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet:
          - 8.0 # EOL: 2026-11-10
          - 7.0 # EOL: 2024-05-14
          - 6.0 # EOL: 2024-11-12
          # version support doc: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        repository: getargv/getargv
        path: getargv
        token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
    - name: Build libgetargv
      run: make install_dylib
      working-directory: getargv
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        path: getargv.cs
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
      id: setup
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet }}.x
    - name: Create temporary global.json
      run: "echo '{\"sdk\":{\"version\": \"${{ steps.setup.outputs.dotnet-version }}\"}}' > ./global.json"
      working-directory: getargv.cs
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
      working-directory: getargv.cs
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore --framework net${{ matrix.dotnet }}
      working-directory: getargv.cs
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
      working-directory: getargv.cs
```

I can set the framework when building with a flag, but the restore step has no such flag.

The error I get is fairly predictable:

```
Error: /Users/runner/.dotnet/sdk/7.0.404/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(160,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. Download the .NET SDK from https://aka.ms/dotnet/download [/Users/runner/work/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/Getargv/Getargv.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0]
Error: /Users/runner/.dotnet/sdk/7.0.404/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(160,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. Download the .NET SDK from https://aka.ms/dotnet/download [/Users/runner/work/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/Getargv.Tool/Getargv.Tool.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0]
Error: /Users/runner/.dotnet/sdk/7.0.404/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(160,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. Download the .NET SDK from https://aka.ms/dotnet/download [/Users/runner/work/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/Getargv.Tests/Getargv.Tests.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0]
Error: /Users/runner/.dotnet/sdk/6.0.417/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 7.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 7.0. [/Users/runner/work/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/Getargv/Getargv.csproj]
Error: /Users/runner/.dotnet/sdk/6.0.417/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 7.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 7.0. [/Users/runner/work/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/Getargv.Tool/Getargv.Tool.csproj]
Error: /Users/runner/.dotnet/sdk/6.0.417/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 7.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 7.0. [/Users/runner/work/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/getargv.cs/Getargv.Tests/Getargv.Tests.csproj]
```

How do people test against older dotnet versions while also supporting newer versions?

Edit:

Changing the build command to: `dotnet build --framework net${{ matrix.dotnet }}` doesn't use the specified framework for restore.

Comment: Wouldnt it be sufficient to install all SDKs and test using the TargetFrameworks tag in the tesproject to configure all target frameworks you want to test. Afaik there is no such thing like a .net version specific dotnet restore. Your setup would only make sense if you want to test sdk version specific behaviors to me.

Comment: # You can test your matrix by printing the current dotnet version
 ```YAML
-name: Display dotnet version    
  run: dotnet --version  
 ```

Comment: The restore can be limited to specific TFM by passing the option to msbuild, e.g. `-p:TargetFramework=net6.0`. You can alternatively use TargetFramework environment variable for the restore step. I wouldn't use it in general as it affects all of operations with dotnet/msbuild.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek your solution worked and was very simple, if you write up an answer i'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: as an option, you can run `dotnet new globaljson` and set version you want to use in the json: `   "sdk": { "version": "8.0.100" }`. The configuration will be applied for all nested folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the target framework for dotnet restore with `dotnet restore -p:TargetFramework=net7.0`.

`dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` are wrappers around `dotnet msbuild`, and `dotnet restore` is actually the same as calling `dotnet msbuild -t:restore`.
Some additional information can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595870/is-it-possible-to-set-the-targetframework-on-the-commandline-with-dotnet-build).

I would try changing your code like this:

```
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore -p:TargetFramework=net${{ matrix.dotnet }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dotnet --version # Check the installed versions
dotnet --list-sdks # List all installed SDKs
dotnet --global install "desired_version" # Install the desired version
```

After specifying the .NET SDK version, execute the dotnet restore command for your multi-target framework project. This command will restore the NuGet packages required for your project.

```
# Navigate to your project directory
cd path/to/your/project

dotnet restore
```

Once the packages are restored, you can run your tests using the dotnet test command. This assumes you have unit tests set up for your project.

```
dotnet test
```

Make sure to adapt the version numbers and paths according to your project's requirements.

Example:

```
# Install .NET SDK 7.0.404
dotnet --global install 7.0.404

# Navigate to your project directory
cd path/to/your/project

# Restore packages
dotnet restore

# Run tests
dotnet test
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail about how the `dotnet --global install` part works? I'm trying to test the code against the version specified in the matrix for that run, and am having trouble with the 'restore' step. However I do not want to install later versions of .net outside of their runs, as I have no way of knowing if they correctly emulate older versions, which is the whole point of the multi version testing.

Comment: @CamdenNarzt I think issue may be in order of your dotnet versions in the matrix. Change them into ascending order same as they are declared in <TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net7.0;net8.0 . It has to align with ```matrix: dotnet: - '6.0.x' - '7.0.x' - '8.0.x'```  Also try remove redundand dotnet restore step. If the dependencies are already restored, dotnet build --no-restore proceeds with building the project. If the dependencies are not restored or if there are changes in the dependencies since the last restore, dotnet build --no-restore performs an implicit restore before building

Comment: The matrix is run concurrently with different runners, the order won't change anything. Each run starts with nothing restored.

Answer (score 0):

## The common Github Actions way to go:

1. [Install all targeted SDKs](https://github.com/stesee/GithubActionsHelloWorld/blob/NetMultiTargetExample/.github/workflows/dotnet.yml)
2. Use the `<TargetFrameworks>` tag in the [test csproj](https://github.com/stesee/GithubActionsHelloWorld/blob/ff2bcce20f44fe57b4028d4bd9563d8d57bde023/GithubActionsHelloWorldTests/GithubActionsHelloWorldTests.csproj#L4C15-L4C15) to pick the .net versions that should be tested. The testrunner will run each test in each .net version listed there.

Thats sufficient for every project I have seen so far.

## Test Matrix approach

If your really really want to test, like you drafted, using a test matrix to ensure support / passed tests on lacking SDKs your approach seems to be reasonable. Things I fixed in your GHA workflow:

1. In this [POC](https://github.com/stesee/GithubActionsHelloWorld/blob/ExplicitNetSdkTestMatrixExample/.github/workflows/dotnet.yml) it seems that the format of your matrix values get messed up -> avoid "." in the version.
2. You need to pick the .net version on running the tests.

```
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, windows-latest]
        dotnet: [8, 7, 6]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet }}.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore --framework net${{ matrix.dotnet }}.0
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal --configuration Release --framework net${{ matrix.dotnet }}.0
```

### Disclaimer

I skipped complexity of global.json and sdk pinning in Directory.Build.props. It does not really make sense in case of explicitly installing/omitting the SDK version anyway. And settings in global.json were related to NETSDK1045 in the [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741953/getting-netsdk1045-the-current-net-sdk-does-not-support-net-core-3-0-as-a-tar#57487260).

A starting point that does not fail (added latestMajor) is e.g.:

```
    - name: Create temporary global.json
      run: "echo '{\"sdk\":{\"version\": \"${{ matrix.dotnet }}.0.0\" ,\"rollForward\": \"latestMajor\" }}' > ./global.json"
```

Comment: Are you sure this will help? It still looks to be restoring .NET 7 and .NET 8 target (in the csproj) with .NET 6 SDK which will fail for the reasons mentioned in the question.

Comment: There are no major differences between the restore of the three mentioned SDKs. Its probably not an issue related to the restore step itself.... The error message of NETSDK1045 indicates a missing .net sdk. Seems to be no restore issue here

Comment: Just to be certain: have you tried to omit the global.json?